# Authorization problems with Embedded Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: glassfish-3, java-ee-5, glassfish-embedded

I'm using Embedded Glassfish to deploy a Java EE 5 web application. Using version 3.1 I was successful to:

Deploy it in a normal (not embedded) environment;

Based on the 1st step, create an embedded deploy.

Then, something changed that I cannot succeed anymore. Every time I try to log-in, I get a 403 error, meaning that my environment is working (could make authentication) but my authorization rules are not good! OK. You can think that it was obviously a codding/configuration problem, but the fact is that the same .WAR can be deployed and runs smoothly when I'm not at an embedded environment (now 3.1.1 version). I've just tried to repeat the two steps above to the 3.1.1 version, but the same error appear.

What can I be doing wrong to this new GlassFish version?